# Bearer авторизация java

Tags: java

Посылаю запрос:

```
private void executeHttpGet(String url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url).openConnection());
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer" + "<my_token>");
    connection.connect();
    connection.getContent();
    System.out.println(connection.getRequestMethod());
}
```

Но запрос падает с 401 ошибкой - нет авторизации. Но через постман с тем же токеном ответ приходит. (get запрос проставляется по умолчанию)

Comment: `"Bearer"` => `"Bearer "`

Comment: хах, спасибо) можете сделать ответ, помечу как решение)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыли пробел в заголовке

```
"Bearer" => "Bearer "
```